# Control Masstransit Exchanges and Bindings

Tags: c#, rabbitmq, masstransit

I am using Masstransit. I would like to avoid to create an exchange for the endpoint and would rather have the endpoint queue to bind directly to the publishing exchange.

This is my code

```
    cfg.Message<Notification>(x => { x.SetEntityName("NOTIFICATION_REQUEST"); });

    g.ReceiveEndpoint("notification-workerQ", e =>        
    {
         e.Consumer<NotificationConsumer>();
    });
```

This creates

- NOTIFICATION_REQUEST  exchange
- notification-workerQ exchange
- notification-workerQ queue

Is there a way to avoid notification-workerQ exchange and have the queue directly bound to NOTIFICATION_REQUEST exchange?

**Additional question**

I am asked to not create an exchange at all but use an already existing topic exchange that I bind my queue to using routing keys.

That means my notification-workerQ should bind to GENERIC_DROP exchange using a routingkey like "componentX.something.notification"

Maybe something like

```
    g.ReceiveEndpoint("notification-workerQ", e =>        
    {
         e.Consumer<NotificationConsumer>(x => 
         { 
            //THIS IS NOT WORKING CODE
            x.consumeFrom("GENERIC_DROP", "ROUTING_KEY") 
         });
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to prevent MassTransit from creating the `notification-workerQ` exchange, as MassTransit always creates a matching exchange for a queue.

You can, however, bind your existing topic exchange, with routing key, by configuring the receive endpoint as shown below.

```cs
e.Bind("NOTIFICATION_REQUEST", x =>
{
    x.RoutingKey = "ROUTING_KEY";
    x.ExchangeType = ExchangeType.Topic;
});
```

> There is also [a sample](https://github.com/MassTransit/Sample-Direct/blob/master/DirectClient/ContentReceivedConsumer.cs#L50) that shows how to use *direct* exchanges, topic exchanges are configured the same way.