MassTransit creates additional exchanges in rabbitmq
I am trying to bind a new Queue to existing exchange. The problem is that, MassTransit additionally
creates a new exchange with a queue name. So, at the end I have two exchanges and one queue.
How can I avoid creating additional exchange and just bind one existing exchange to a queue ?
here is my configuration:
serviceCollection.AddMassTransit(busConfig =>
{
    busConfig.SetKebabCaseEndpointNameFormatter();
    busConfig.AddConsumer<TransactionListener>();
            
    busConfig.UsingRabbitMq((context, cfg) =>
            {
                IOptions<MessageQueueOptions> messageQueueOptions = context.GetRequiredService<IOptions<MessageQueueOptions>>();
                IOptions<QueuesOptions> queueOptions = context.GetRequiredService<IOptions<QueuesOptions>>();

                cfg.Host(messageQueueOptions.Value.Uri, "/", rabbitConfig =>
                {
                    rabbitConfig.Username(messageQueueOptions.Value.Username!);
                    rabbitConfig.Password(messageQueueOptions.Value.Password!);
                });

                #region Transactions

                cfg.ReceiveEndpoint(queueOptions.Value.TransactionsQueue!, configEndpoint =>
                {
                    configEndpoint.ConfigureConsumeTopology = false;
                    configEndpoint.ConcurrentMessageLimit = 10;

                    configEndpoint.Bind(queueOptions.Value.TransactionsExchange);

                    configEndpoint.UseRawJsonDeserializer();
                    configEndpoint.ConfigureConsumer<TransactionListener>(context);
                });

                #endregion
    });
});

Here is a screen:

I do not want to transactions.queue be presented in the exchange list.

Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/a/70127550/1882
